# Cannot import module mariadb

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, mariadb

I use python 3.9 on MacOS 11.2.2 and want to use mariadb, which is installed ("mariadb 10.5.9 is already installed and up-to-date").

However, python cannot import the module mariadb, and I get this error:

```
import mariadb  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._mariadb import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/_mariadb.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_ps_fetch_functions
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/_mariadb.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/_mariadb.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

Pls help correct this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you followed [those](https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/install.html#build-prerequisites) steps or just ran `pip install mariadb`?

Comment: @gribvirus74. The steps are not all that helpful. Yes, I have python installed, yes, mariaDB is installed and it should install the connector with it. Is this a PATH problem?

Comment: I doubt it. My guess is that it has something to do with these C libs. But I think even if you don't have them on your system, it should install a binary package or fail on installation.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment...

_mariadb.cpython-39-darwin.so should be linked against libmariadb.3.dylib and the latter one should provide the exported symbol mysql_ps_fetch_functions.

To determine the problem I would suggest the following:

1. Check that mariadb.cpython-39-darwin.so is linked against Connector/C:

`ldd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/_mariadb.cpython-39-darwin.so` should list libmariadb.3.dylib

2. Determine the location of libmariadb.3.dylib and check the output of

`nm libmariadb.3.dylib | grep mysql_ps_fetch_functions`.

If output doesn't list the mysql_ps_fetch_functions api call, your installed C/C version is too old, or you have multiple instances of C/C installed.
Homebrew e.g. provides the latest version 3.1.12, to use this version make sure that setup.py will find mariadb_config of the latest installation.

As an alternative you could also build C/C and C/Python from source.

I know that the installation is not very comfortable, but providing generic binaries for non windows platforms doesn't work well due to too much dependencies (like TLS libraries).

Comment: the first command (the mac  equivalent for `ldd` is `otool -L`): otool -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/_mariadb.cpython-39-darwin.so
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/_mariadb.cpython-39-darwin.so:
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)

Comment: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/nm: error: libmariadb.3.dylib: No such file or directory.

Comment: I am ready to give up. I wish there were an installer for the Mac -- after all the MacOS is not some obscure flavor nobody'd ever want to install MariaDB on.

Comment: If libmariadb.3.dylib was not found it means it is not installed. Did you try e.g. `brew install mariadb-connector-c` ?

Comment: Sorry this didn't work either. I do appreciate your trying to help.

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't very verbose. If C/C couldn't be found after pip install there should be an error message. If C/C was found, but can't be loaded it's likely that there is a unsupported/outdated version installed. Also make sure that you did a pip uninstall mariadb before trying again.

Comment: @KOwen-ReinstateMonica did you manage to resolve the issue? I'm facing it right now.